# "Spring Boot and OAuth2" tutorial does not work

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I followed the [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) tutorial step by step. When I visit `http://127.0.0.1:9999/client/` in my browser, I expect that it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/` but it asks me username and password.[image: password requirement]

Have I made a mistake?

Comment: Are you permiting the requests to the `login/**` path in your configuration?

Comment: I permiting `/login**` in `SocialApplication.java`.